# App designer points don't appear on the plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-app-designer

I am using for the first time AppDesigner (MATLAB). I am trying to plot systolic and diastolic blood pressure but nothing shows? I watched some videos online but still, I can't figure out what I am doing wrong... Could you please help me?

```
        timeline=app.time.Value;
        diastolic=app.DIA.Value;
        systolic=app.SYS.Value;
        plot(app.UIAxes,timeline,systolic);
        hold(app.UIAxes,'on');
        plot(app.UIAxes,timeline,diastolic);
        hold(app.UIAxes,'off');
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What function is the code you shared in? Is the callback even triggered?

Comment: Yes, the callback is triggered. I found my mistake: I should have written "scatter()" instead of plot(), thank you for your help :)